# C++ machine learning framework

Tags: c++, frameworks, artificial-intelligence, machine-learning

I can't seem to find a C++ based ML/AI framework that implements a wide variety of neural network algorithms. I've used [Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog) for these purposes when working in Java, but I don't see anything that's similar, functionality-wise, in C++. The closest I've seen is FANN, but it lacks some stuff, LMA & annealing for example.

EDIT: The best alternative I've found is [Shark](http://shark-project.sourceforge.net/GettingStarted.html#), but as I said, it's still lacking and has only the more commonly used features, no LMA, annealing or PSO or anything of that level.

Comment: The google fu is weak but looks like the encog team has a spin-off: http://code.google.com/p/encog-cpp/

Comment: @AJG85 Last commit in it is Oct 2010, looks pretty dead to me...

Comment: @TC1 you say dead, I say **final**. :)

Comment: @JoãoPortela You should really take a look at those 13 commits before you say **final**... :)

Comment: Encog doesn't look like a very complete framework.  I think you are asking for a C++ version of Encog, rather than a diverse ML framework.  If so, then you're looking for neural nets, to be precise.  Similarly, if someone came along asking for a counterpart to, say, Shogun, in a different language, it would be obvious they're SVM-centric, rather than interested in NNs.  Neural Networks, like SVMs, or decision trees, or what have you, are just a small part of machine learning and AI.

Comment: There seems to be a C++ implementation of encog as of now. Have not tried it yet, though. https://github.com/encog/encog-c/downloads

Comment: C/C++ Perceptron: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccperceptron/

Comment: Can someone add a comment link point to the latest solution? This one seems too old but google point here...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ok, so after a few days of on and off searching, I think I can pretty safely say that **there is no such thing**. None of the existing libs provide anything even close to the level of sophistication of Encog, and since one of the main reasons I wanted it in C++ was the fact that I kind of need QT integration, I suppose I'll just end up using Encog and Jambi.

Anyway, to those who stumble upon this somewhat later on / from Google, there's basically three frameworks/libraries that do offer somewhat reasonable features, and they should really be enough if you don't want LMA, PSO, annealing or any of that more exotic stuff:

- [Shark](http://image.diku.dk/shark/)
- [dlib](http://dlib.net/), also mentioned by ffh
- [OpenCV's ML library](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/index.html) mentioned by rics

That's pretty much it. The rest is immature/dead or just really too lacking functionality-wise to mention. If I ever decide to roll my own project (quite possible, as I pretty much need it for work), I'll be sure to update this place with a link.

Answer (score 8):

The [mloss](http://mloss.org/software/) repository has a number of C++ based open source machine learning frameworks. Personally, I find [dlib](http://dlib.net/) quite useful.

Comment: You may also want to look at the [MLPACK C++ library](http://mlpack.org), which has many machine learning algorithms

Answer (score 2):

[Encog](http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog/) is in the process of being ported to C/C++.

https://github.com/encog/encog-c

Answer (score 2):

This is the best one I have ever seen for Neural Networks: [EBLearn](http://eblearn.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Better provide some details. Like how and why you think its the best.

Answer (score 1):

Although OpenCV is primarily used for computer vision its [machine learning library](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/ml/doc/ml.html) (ml) contains classes that handle decision trees, Bayes classifier, multi-layer perceptron, boosting etc.

Comment: Pretty neat, better than anything I'd found, but still, the MLP section only supports RProp...